# Firebase not reporting android activity

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using Firebase for push notifications for Android and iOS, and all the notifications are working perfectly.
But when I log into firebase, and try to see the activity in “Streamview”, I see only iOS activity, and nothing for Android.
I do see the activity in Cloud messaging’s Report section, for both iOS and Android.

The application we have built is built using Xamarin forms.

One thing to note from the Firebase console is that it doesn’t appear as though the console recognizes that SDK setup was fully complete.

When going into the link where it says “Continue SDK Setup”.

Finally, when proceeding to step #4 it tries to verify that there has been communication between the app and Google’s servers and it doesn’t seem to find anything and it just sits there looking. 
Notifications appear to work, but the app just doesn’t seem to be registering as being used under the Android side.

Any pointers in this direction will be very helpful.

i don't have any idea what is wrong here.

I want to watch complete report of my push notifications sending count, for both platform Android and iOS. but i am getting only iOS report in stream view tab not for Android.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the exactly the same problem and just keep running into dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

I made the comment above and now I have found an answer, at least for my situation. I had added `Xamarin.Firebase.Core` to the PCL project as the documentation suggests. Later I saw documentation for Android Java that showed Firebase Core being added to the gradle file at the app level. So I added `Xamarin.Firebase.Core` NuGet package to the Android project also and now I can see data for Android in the Firebase Console.